# Class is implemented in in both /Users/... and /Applications/... . One of the two fill be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: xcode, swift

I know this is a common error message when using unit tests, but I'm not doing any of that. Here's what I do:

- I make a new Command Line Tool project
- I put a breakpoint at the `print("Hello, World!")` line
- I type something like `po 3+3` into the console

Then I get this message:

> objc[929]: Class _TtCs18_EmptyArrayStorage is implemented in both /Users/tim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-hlekdhnmnvllzganostmsaamwjje/Build/Products/Debug/TestProject and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx/libswiftCore.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Not just for `_TtCs18_EmptyArrayStorage`, but also for `_TtCs24_ContiguousArrayStorage1` and about two dozen more.

I didn't do anything to my project (not even change any code) so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I even did a clean install on my Mac a couple of days ago. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Did you try `expr 3+3` instead? — Also the fact that it mentions a toolchain is suggestive; did you install a toolchain?

Comment: `expr 3+3`, or basically anything else in the debugger, results in the same. I haven't installed a toolchain - one of the reasons I did a clean install was because of this problem, but it's unfortunately still here.

Comment: Can you give any more details about your system, your Xcode version...?

Comment: Also you say you did a "clean install" but what does that mean? You installed the whole system? Did actually erase the hard disk? Or did you just re-download Xcode? In which case, have you tried cleaning the caches?

Comment: I did a clean install of OS X El Capitan, so I did actually erase the entire OS X partition. I downloaded Xcode 7.3 from developer.apple.com/downloads.

Comment: OK, good answer. Trying it on El Capitan / Xcode 7.3, I can reproduce it, no problem. So I think we can conclude this is just Xcode 7.3 sucking. File a bug report! http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt.

Comment: I just got that when using "Print Description of ..." in the debugger. More than 2 year and this debugger is still a piece of scrap.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I haven't had that bug once in Xcode 8 betas 2 and 3 :)

Comment: Sounds good. I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried that beta. I better shouldn't have. Starts with the daily Swift syntax change, continues with not working compiler warnings and does not end with cmd-/ not working. Rotten Apple, I guess. Hope I wake up from that nightmare soon. I must be dreaming :-(

Comment: @ThomasKilian restarting Xcode fixed the comment bug for me, not sure about the compiler warnings!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when I was building and running from Xcode 7.3.1. 
I also had the beta 8 version also install. (Not sure if the specific versions matter, but listing anyway.)

I am guessing if there are multiple Xcode apps installed and you attempt to use the non-system specified version, this error may eventually display.

I was able to verify this by executing:

```
sudo xcode-select -p
```

The output was something like:

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

I was able to resolve this problem by running:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

If this doesn't resolve your issue, I hope you find a working alternative solution. :)

Comment: I definitely only had one version of Xcode installed, but I'm glad this solved the problem for you! It appears that they fixed it in Xcode 8.

Comment: This would show both paths under /Applications - in the OP (ang now mine) the code is the Xcode and something in the build has copied the swift libraries to DerivedData