# iOS swiftUI app warning RSABSSATokenBlinder is implemented in two locations

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

```
objc[68450]: Class RSABSSATokenBlinder is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CryptoKitPrivate.framework/CryptoKitPrivate (0x15e118328) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CryptoKitCBridging.framework/CryptoKitCBridging (0x15b244400). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[68450]: Class RSABSSATokenWaitingActivation is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CryptoKitPrivate.framework/CryptoKitPrivate (0x15e118350) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CryptoKitCBridging.framework/CryptoKitCBridging (0x15b244428). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[68450]: Class RSABSSATokenReady is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CryptoKitPrivate.framework/CryptoKitPrivate (0x15e1183a0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CryptoKitCBridging.framework/CryptoKitCBridging (0x15b244478). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[68450]: Class RSABSSATokenIssuer is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CryptoKitPrivate.framework/CryptoKitPrivate (0x15e118418) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CryptoKitCBridging.framework/CryptoKitCBridging (0x15b2444f0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I am building a basic SwiftUI app with CoreData. This warning shows up in console on Xcode 13.2.1. I have reinstalled Xcode, used App Store version as well as Xcode from apple developer website.

To reproduce this, create a new Xcode project for an iOS app. Run the app in an iPhone simulator.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38679826/13550412

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem running on the simulator.  These 'warnings' disappeared when I ran on a device.